# What are the valid symbols for a React 'key'

Tags: reactjs

What are the valid symbols for a react key prop as such;

```
<div key="can i use spaces for example?"></div>
```

In my case I want to use a URL as the key

```
const links = [
    {
        label: 'foo label',
        href: 'https://example.com/foo',
    },
    {
        label: 'bar label',
        href: 'https://example.com/bar',
    }
]

links.map(
    link => (<a key={link.href} href={link.href}>{link.label}</a>)
);
```

Is this valid? I was thinking that I could use some hash function to pass the href through first, but this is a pointless step if any character is guaranteed to be valid in a key value.

The reason I'm asking is that I can't find any example in the doc that uses a non-alpha-numeric character for the key, and also explicitly says that, if you don't have an ID to use as key for the object you're rendering you can `hash some part of it to make a key`. Although this could be because you shouldn't use very long keys, and should therefor hash the content first to truncate it's size, it seems that the whole documentation implicitly says that only alpha-numeric characters should be used as a key.

Answer (score 6):

Requirements for React's key is best described in the documentation for [reconciliation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#keys)

> In practice, finding a key is not really hard. Most of the time, the
>   element you are going to display already has a unique id. When that's
>   not the case, you can add a new ID property to your model or hash some
>   parts of the content to generate a key. Remember that the key only has
>   to be unique among its siblings, not globally unique.

So, the key should be unique (amongst its siblings) and stable.

Your example, therefore, is a good fit.  Spaces should be fine as well.

Comment: Although the excerpt you posted does not explicitly say anything about invalid strings to use in a key, it does say that "you can hash some part of the content to generate a key".
Although this doesn't necessarily mean that some characters are invalid, it seems that it could mean that. And even though react does not seem to crash for any characters(URL's does seem to work for instance), this does not necessarily mean that it is "supported" and will be in the future.

Comment: Not sure if the original example has changed, but the key in that case is *not* a good fit, because the url is not unique among its siblings.  Better to use the label in this case.

Comment: For the sake of anyone finding this question now: David Calhoun observation was an oversight in my part. The urls where supposed to be unique. Question has been edited.